# center custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass with width of 300.

Since the cell is 20pt shorter than the table view, When the cells get loaded, its placed on the left most position, is there a way to center this custom cell to the tableview's center?

I tried `cell.center = self.tableView.center` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but it wont work. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad your custom cell with 10px to the left so it will only appear to be centered, so you just make the width 310 and move everything else inside by 10 px.

Comment: this is correct because you might want the header view to be the same size as the table view!

Answer (score 1):

a) Resize your UITableView to 300 and center it.
or
b) Make your cell's width same as UITableView's width. Make your custom cell's background color clearColor. Add one more view to your custom cell subclass that will contain every other view and add every view in that view. Think of this like an illusion where the cell is actually wider but it's contents are centered in a fake view.